# Recursive toString()

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I have a doubleLinkedList and need to implement a recursive toString() method without parameters. Here is what I have, and it throws a NullPointerException

```
//Print forwards
public String recursiveToString(){
  return first.rTS();
}

//Print backwards
public String recursiveBackwardsString(){
  return last.rBS();
}


    //Recursive helper in the node class
    public String rBS(){
      if (this!=null)
        return info+" "+back.rBS();
      return "";
    }

    //Recursive helper in the node class
    public String rTS(){
      if (this!=null)
        return info+" "+next.rTS();
      return "";
    }
```

Comment: where is info defined ?

Comment: Where are `first`, `last`, `back`, and `next` defined? One of them is `null`.

Comment: Also, `this` can never be `null` according to the JLS.

Comment: this can never be null

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

`this` won't be `null` in any code, if some method in `null` is called, the NullPointerException is thrown before the body of method is reached, so, the protection from `null` here is incorrect:

```
if (this != null)
    return ...
```

You should write it in this way:

```
public String rBS(){
    if (back != null)
        return info+" "+back.rBS();
    return info;
}
```

and the same thing for `rTS`.

Comment: if back is null this will throw a NullPointerException, the check should be if(back != null)

Comment: @Martin Oh, that's exactly what I mean to write, thanks!